# Flask dance Facebook login error on Google cloud run

Tags: python, facebook, flask, web, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to add Facebook login using Flask-Dance on my website, but I'm having some issues. Locally, using ssl_context='adhoc', it works fine. But when I try to login on my app that is running on Google Cloud Run I'm getting into the following error:

> Default
> 2021-04-07T02:16:12.738640ZTraceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise raise value File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flask_dance/consumer/oauth2.py", line 256, in authorized token = self.session.fetch_token( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_session.py", line 239, in fetch_token self._client.parse_request_uri_response( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/web_application.py", line 203, in parse_request_uri_response response = parse_authorization_code_response(uri, state=state) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 262, in parse_authorization_code_response raise InsecureTransportError() oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InsecureTransportError: (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
facebook_blueprint = make_facebook_blueprint(scope='email', login_url='/facebook')
facebook_blueprint.backend = SQLAlchemyStorage(OAuth, db.session, user=current_user)

@users.route('/login-facebook')    
def login_facebook():
    if not facebook.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for('facebook.login'))

    account_info = facebook.get('/me?fields=name,email')
    if account_info.ok:
        account_info_json = account_info.json()
        check_facebook_account(email = account_info_json['email'], name = account_info_json['name'])
        return redirect(url_for('artes_e_telas.artes_finalizadas'))

@oauth_authorized.connect_via(facebook_blueprint)
def facebook_logged_in(blueprint, token):
    account_info = blueprint.session.get('/me?fields=name,email')

    if account_info.ok:
        account_info_json = account_info.json()
        check_facebook_account(email = account_info_json['email'], name = account_info_json['name'])
        return redirect(url_for('artes_e_telas.artes_finalizadas'))
```

This "check_facebook_account" is just to commit the result on the database.

On Cloud Run log I can see that really exists a http request:

> 2021-04-06 22:17:26.728 BRT
> GET
> 302
> 673 B
> 5 ms
> https://rapiart.com.br/login-facebook

> 2021-04-06 22:17:26.900 BRT
> GET
> 302
> 0 ms
> http://rapiart.com.br/facebook

> 2021-04-06 22:17:27.068 BRT
> GET
> 302
> 1.46 KiB
> 6 ms
> https://rapiart.com.br/facebook

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same, any updates?